Como puedo utilizar correctamente JPA con JSP con intellij Idea
Ayuda, nececito crear las clases de entidades para la persistencia, estoy utilizando eclipseLink, y utilizando java EE 8, con el IDE Intellij Idea ultimate.
Nececito ayuda, debo realizarlo sin SpringBoot.
